# Apache redirects

Tags: server, permissions, apache2

I have a server called dad.co.uk. This used to work in a very standard way. My daughter wanted me to host her website for free and so her site girl.co.uk now lives in

`/home/daughter/public_html`  and mine in
`/home/father/public_html`   and *almost* everything works.

In order to get to my site you have to do www.dad.co.uk and if you put just dad.co.uk you get redirected to daughter.co.uk.  Why is it not going to my `.../father/public_html`?

I want anything asking for dad.co.uk to try dad.co.uk and anything to girl.co.uk to go to her site

I have these virtual hosts defined  (I have removed pointy brackets to get this system to display)

```
VirtualHost www.daughter.co.uk:80  
    DocumentRoot /home/rachel/public_html/daughter  
    Directory /home/rachel/public_html/daughter  
        allow from all  
        Options None  
        Require all granted  
    /Directory  
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log  
    LogLevel warn  
/VirtualHost  


VirtualHost www.dad.co.uk:80
    DocumentRoot /home/father/public_html  
    Directory "/home/father/public_html"  
        allow from all  
        Options None  
        Require all granted  
    /Directory  
/VirtualHost  


VirtualHost dad.co.uk:80  
    DocumentRoot /home/father/public_html  
    Directory /home/father/public_html  
        allow from all  
        Options None  
        Require all granted  
    /Directory  
/VirtualHost
```

Nothing appears in the error_log

Comment: Why did you use two VirtualHost files for daddy?

Comment: Please look at point 4 and 5 in my answer on the proposed duplication. You should use `<VirtualHost *:80>` and `ServerName` directive inside.